# What's the name of the OSX look up "Dialog / Pop-up"?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to find the name and the corresponding API documentation for the tooltip-like dialog that opens up when you click "Look Up..."
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for [NSPopOver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopover).